# Attach multiple PDFs to an email - do loop skips first PDF for second and subsequent iterations

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I want to scan through a folder to pick relevant PDFs belonging to a person, such as AAA, and attach them to an email to be sent to AAA. Then move on to pick up PDFs belonging to BBB and attach them to an email to be sent to BBB so on.

My folder containing the PDFs looks like this:

- AAA_111111.pdf
- AAA_222222.pdf
- AAA_333333.pdf
- BBB_111111.pdf
- BBB_222222.pdf
- BBB_333333.pdf
- CCC_777777.pdf
- CCC_888888.pdf
- CCC_999999.pdf
- CCC_444444.pdf

The person is identified by the letters before the underscore (initials) and there is a list on another Excel tab that the initials are looked up against to return their email address.

The code below will generate the email for person AAA and attach all three files listed above.
On the next pass of the main (outer) "do while" loop it comes to person BBB but the inner "do while mfe=" loop attaches the second and third files, but doesn't attach BBB_111111.pdf.
For the third loop, the "do while mfe=" loop attaches the latter three files for CCC but doesn't attach CCC_777777.pdf.

```vb
Sub emailreports()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim OMail As Object, signature, mfe, sto As String
    Dim emaillastrow, x, a As Long
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim folder, strfile As String
    Dim rundate As Date
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.AutoRecover.Enabled = False
    
    folder = Worksheets("START").Range("A14")
    strfile = Dir(folder)
    rundate = Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E7")
    b = Worksheets("START").Range("H25")
    
    Sheets("EMAIL").Select
    emaillastrow = Worksheets("EMAIL").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    
    If Dir(folder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "PDF destination file path doesn't exist.", vbcritial, "Path error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Do While Len(strfile) > 0
        Filename = fso.GetBaseName(folder & strfile)
        mfe = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, "_") - 1)
            
        For x = 2 To emaillastrow
            If mfe = Worksheets("EMAIL").Range("A" & x) Then
                sto = sto & ";" & Worksheets("EMAIL").Range("B" & x)
            End If
        Next
            
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .Display
        End With
        With OutMail
            .To = LCase(sto)
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Test subject text"
            Do While mfe = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, "_") - 1)
                .Attachments.Add (folder & Filename)
                Filename = Dir
                If Filename = "" Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
            .signature.Delete
            .HTMLBody = "<font face=""arial"" style=""font-size:10pt;"">" & "Test email body text" & .HTMLBody
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
            
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
            
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        Set OutAccount = Nothing
            
Skip:
        sto = ""
        strfile = Filename
    
    Loop
    
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.AutoRecover.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I thought, at the end of generating the email, to take a step back but being a Do loop this is not possible.
My code seems to ignore the PDF that it stopped at as part of the previous email generation and when generating the next email starts from that PDF file but only picks up and attaches subsequent PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary object to group together the filenames by prefix with one pass of the directory and then iterate the dictionary keys to create the emails with corresponding attachments. For example (outlook methods untested)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub emailreports()
   
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary, key
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim folder As String, strfile As String, mfe As String
    Dim sTo As String, arPDF, arAddr, f
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long, emaillastrow As Long
    
    folder = Worksheets("START").Range("A14")
    strfile = Dir(folder & "*.pdf")
    If strfile = "" Then
        MsgBox "PDF destination file path doesn't exist.", vbCritical, "Path error " & folder
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' group files by prefix
        Do While strfile <> ""
            mfe = Left(strfile, InStr(strfile, "_") - 1)
            If dict.Exists(mfe) Then
                dict(mfe) = dict(mfe) & vbTab & strfile
            Else
                dict.Add mfe, strfile
            End If
            strfile = Dir ' get next pdf
        Loop
    End If
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("EMAIL")
    emaillastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' read email address lookup into array
    arAddr = ws.Range("A2:B" & emaillastrow)
    
    ' prepare one email per key
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, OMail As Object
    'Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    For Each key In dict.Keys
                
        ' build array of file names for one key
        mfe = Trim(key)
        arPDF = Split(dict(mfe), vbTab)
        
        ' get email addresses
        sTo = ""
        For r = 1 To UBound(arAddr)
            If mfe = arAddr(r, 1) Then
                sTo = sTo & arAddr(r, 2) & ";"
            End If
        Next
        Debug.Print key, sTo
               
        'Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        'With OutMail
                     
            '.To = LCase(sTo)
            '.cc = ""
            '.BCC = ""
            '.Subject = "Test subject text"
            ' attach pdfs
            For Each f In arPDF
                '.Attachments.Add folder & f
                Debug.Print , folder & f
            Next
            '.signature.Delete
            '.HTMLBody = "<font face=""arial"" style=""font-size:10pt;"">" & "Test email body text" & .HTMLBody
            '.Display
        
        'End With
    Next
    
    'OutApp.quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much CDP1802, this works perfectly for me! I've never used dictionary before and will go away and read up to understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

`On Error Resume Next` seems to mask errors and hide skip reason. Try to use more specialized filename mask:

```
...
folder = Worksheets("START").Range("A14")
If Dir(folder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox "PDF destination file path doesn't exist.", vbcritial, "Path error"
    Exit Sub
End If
strfile = Dir(fso.BuildPath(folder, "*_*.pdf")
rundate = Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E7")
b = Worksheets("START").Range("H25")
'Sheets("EMAIL").Select 'no need to select a sheet
emaillastrow = Worksheets("EMAIL").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
```

...